# Passing environment variables to angular library

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I've created company internal library using angualr2-library yeoman generator.

Some of the angular services are using environment variables in our current applications (api endpoints are changed on each env). I was wondering what is the best way to pass the current environment object to the angular2 library services?

Comment: Did you get an answer for this? I want to do the exact same thing

Answer (score 94, accepted):

In case you still searching for a solution, here's how I accomplished something simliar to what you were asking for (using Angular 4.2.4).

In your `AppModule` (or the place where you want to import your library), call the `forRoot()` method on your `LibraryModule`. With the help of this function, you can pass any config values to you library, e.g. your app's environment.

```
import {environment} from "../environments/environment";
...

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        ...
        LibraryModule.forRoot(environment)
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

---

You `LibraryModule` of course needs to offer the `forRoot()` method.
In the providers array you then can provide services, values [and more](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injector-providers). In this case, `'env'` acts as the token holding the given environment object for simplicity. You can also use an [InjectionToken](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injectiontoken) instead.

```
@NgModule({
    ...
})
export class LibraryModule {

    public static forRoot(environment: any): ModuleWithProviders {

        return {
            ngModule: LibraryModule,
            providers: [
                ImageService,
                {
                    provide: 'env', // you can also use InjectionToken
                    useValue: environment
                }
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

Since the token `env` is now provided by your `LibraryModule`, you can inject it in all of its child services or components.

```
@Injectable()
export class ImageService {

    constructor(private http: Http, @Inject('env') private env) {
    }

    load(): Observable<any> {
        // assume apiUrl exists in you app's environment:
        return this.http.get(`${this.env.apiUrl}/images`)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

}
```

Comment: This is nice idea but in my case my appModule is also use environment variable and it dependes on if my Library changes something? But both are not in sync. is there a was it can be resolved

Comment: What if I want to change `environment` value and want to display changed environment values in my appModule? Can I do that. Because when LibraryModule changes environment value outside app module, it does not reflect in app module @Günter Zöchbauer

Comment: @pschild i did exactly what you have said, i get the environment configuration in the providers array, but when inject it in the service the value is undefined. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @bsh It's hard to say what's going on. Could you create a simple Demo with [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) showing the problem? Which version of Angular do you use?

Comment: Instead of forRoot()-method I use  InjectionToken for each paramater what I need in library. then main app will provide them.

Comment: @pschild then how would you perform the conditional loading of development module in library like   !environment.production ? StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument() : []

Answer (score 51):

I found an alternative solution to this problem in [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/208). The solution in the GitHub thread has a bug (a typo), so I'm including the fixed solution here:

To begin, add a provider to your top-level AppModule that contains your environment file.

```
import {environment} from '../environments/environment'

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {provide: 'environment', useValue: environment}
  ]
  // object properties omitted for brevity...
})
class AppModule {}
```

Finally, make use of an Inject decorator to include your environment file in any other part of your application you wish (library or otherwise):

```
@Component({
  // object properties omitted for brevity
})
class MyComponent {

  private environment

  constructor(
    @Inject('environment')
    environment
  ) {
    this.environment = environment
  }

}
```

Comment: you nailed it. Nice one

Comment: The best solution   elegant and simple as it should be.

Comment: This solution is worked the best for me, clean and minimal. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

A complete working solution using Angular 11. Assuming you generated a library named `library1` using the command `ng generate library library1`.

> AppModule file

```
// Your other imports ...
import { Library1Module } from 'library1';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,

    // Pass the data you want to share with your library. Here we will pass 'apiUrl'. 
    Library1Module.forRoot({ apiUrl: environment.apiUrl }),

    AppRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> library1.module.ts ('Library1' module main file):

```
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Configurations } from './configurations';
import { Library1Component } from './library1.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [Library1Component],
  imports: [CommonModule],
  exports: [Library1Component]
})
export class Library1Module {

  // Create this static method in the library module.
  public static forRoot(config: Configurations): ModuleWithProviders<Library1Module> {

    return {
      ngModule: Library1Module,
      providers: [
        { provide: Configurations, useValue: config }
      ]
    };
  }

}
```

> configurations.ts (Declare this class inside 'projects\library1\src\lib' folder). Declare all the configurations you need to get from the 'environment' file.

```
export class Configurations {
  public apiUrl: string;

  constructor() {
    this.apiUrl = '';
  }

}
```

> library1.service.ts ('Library1Service' will receive the config object).

```
import { Injectable, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { Configurations } from './configurations';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Library1Service {

  private _apiUrl = 'No value';

  constructor(@Optional() config?: Configurations) {
    if (config) {
      this._apiUrl = config.apiUrl;
    }
  }

  get apiUrl() {
    return this._apiUrl;
  }

}
```

> library1.component.ts (Library1 Component that uses the configuration data).

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Library1Service } from '../public-api';

@Component({
  selector: 'lib-library1',
  template: `
    <p>
      This component inside "library1" library and reads the values from "environment.ts" file.
    </p>

    <h1>API URL : {{apiUrl}}</h1>`
})
export class Library1Component {
  apiUrl = '';

  constructor(library1Service: Library1Service) {
    this.apiUrl = library1Service.apiUrl;
  }
}
```

> app.component.ts (Confirm that the URL already passed to your library by using the library1 component).

```
.......
<lib-library1></lib-library1>
.......
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to pass the environment variable for firebase, simply use this in your library:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [MyAngularComponent],
  exports: [MyAngularComponent],
  imports: [
    AngularFireModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class MyAngularModule {

  public static forRoot(firebaseConfig: FirebaseOptions): ModuleWithProviders<MyAngularModule> {

    return {
      ngModule: MyAngularModule,
      providers: [
        { provide: FIREBASE_OPTIONS, useValue: firebaseConfig }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And import it just like AngularFire...

```js
MyAngularModule.forRoot(environment.firebase)
```

From this post: [pass angularFire config imported in library using forRoot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49776296/pass-angularfire-config-imported-in-library-using-forroot/54831986#54831986)

Answer (score -3):

If You are still looking for the answer.
In the current version i.e. Angular > 6, you don't have to do anything.

The angular-cli commands "ng build --prod (for Production)& ng build (for Development)" will take care of it for you.

Example: If you are running the project in development environment, all the variables are captured from src/environments/environment.ts. 
In your component library project just import "import { environment } from 'environments/environment';" (please make sure about the path)  will takecare of the environment depending upon the angular-cli build command.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  When I tried doing a build, I got an error: "File '<longpathhere>/environment.ts' is not under 'rootDir'

Comment: I think this will work only when there is no projects folder and only src folder with your code. Then compiler will found correct environment file. But if you use environment/environment import under projects directory it will not take projects own environment file rather than environment file from src folder. I fix this situation by using tsconfig paths configuration and added @environment path to 'projects/MyProject/src/environment'