# pass angularFire config imported in library using forRoot

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I use angularFire2 in a custom library

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFirestoreModule
  ]
})
export class CustomModule {
  static forRoot(firebaseConfig: FirebaseOptions): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
    ...
    }
  }
}
```

the consumer library call CustomModule.forRoot({config...})

My question is how do I make the config data available in AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig) ?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem couple of weeks ago, what you have to do is drop the `initializeApp` call in the imports section, and add the `FirebaseOptionsToken` to your `forRoot` declaration like below:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AngularFireModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule
  ]
})
export class CustomModule {
  static forRoot(firebaseConfig: FirebaseOptions): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
       ngModule: CustomModule,
       providers: [
           { provide: FirebaseOptionsToken, useValue: firebaseConfig }
       ]
    }
  }
}
```

If you look at the `initializeApp` method [in Angular/Fire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/b91cd5a84c04628858e09ff19738e5797bd3f88c/src/core/firebase.app.module.ts#L60) you see how it does the same thing when it is called.

It worked for me, hopefully will help others having the same issue.

Comment: Thanks @jair Milanes,  I ran into the same situation and your solution just works.

Comment: And change FirebaseOptionsToken to FIREBASE_OPTIONS in newest version...