# Angular Apollo inject URI into graphql.module.ts

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, graphql, apollo-angular

I am in the process of making an Angular library that includes auth/graphql related code that all our apps require.

Issue is, I store the `uri` in an Angular environment variable, which do not exist in an Angular libraries.

Performing an `ng add apollo-angular` generates the following module:

**graphql.module.ts** (removed imports for clarity):

```
const uri = ''; // <-- add the URL of the GraphQL server here
export function createApollo(httpLink: HttpLink) {
  return {
    link: httpLink.create({uri}),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  };
}

@NgModule({
  exports: [ApolloModule, HttpLinkModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
      useFactory: createApollo,
      deps: [HttpLink],
    },
  ],
})
export class GraphQLModule {}
```

Notice the `uri`, which creates a dependency on this module which *should* be injected.

In my apps `app.module.ts`, I created a provider which grabs the environment:

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: 'envVars', useValue: environment
    }
  ]
```

Which I typically inject via the constructor like so:

```
constructor(@Inject('envVars') private envVars: any) {}
```

I've tried many ways to inject this `uri` to no avail! Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem found at this StackOverflow post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46791075/1207856

However I tweaked mine for my unique situation.

First in AppModule app.module.ts, provide the environment using the `forRoot()` static method:

`GraphQLModule.forRoot(environment)`

Second, in your libraries module, you can set that environment to a static member of your class, as such:

```
export class GraphQLModule {
  public static envVars: any

  public static forRoot(environment: any): ModuleWithProviders {
    // this is to provide to this module non-class section
    this.envVars = environment

    // this is provide to children
    return {
      ngModule: GraphQLModule,
      providers: [
        {
            provide: 'envVars', 
            useValue: environment
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now I can use it statically in this actual module itself or via `@Inject` in any child component or module that uses this module.

So in this actual module I can do this:

`GraphQLModule.envVars.gatewayUri`

or in another class's constructor, I can do this:

`constructor(@Inject('envVars') private envVars: any) {}`

Enjoy!