# Using Injected Token to configure a lazily loaded module

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection, angular-providers, angular-dependency-injection

Consider the following snippet. How do I access the provided value of `Environment` in `forRoot`? Is there an alternate way that I do the same?

```js
interface Environment {
  tokens: Record<string, string>;
}

const ENVIRONMENT = new InjectionToken<Environment>('ENVIRONMENT');

// `SomeModule` with `forRoot` to configure it. This module is from an external library.

// Some library module that I'm creating
@NgModule({
  imports: SomeModule.forRoot() // `tokens` needs to passed here.
})
export class MyLibraryModule {}
```

`MyLibraryModule` will be consumed in some application where `ENVIRONMENT` will be injected. It will be lazily loaded

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing environment variables to angular library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43529920/passing-environment-variables-to-angular-library)

Comment: No. I have updated the question. Two differences: `MyLibraryModule` will be lazily loaded. And, I will not have access to actual environment, only the injected token.